# Better understanding on how to pass variables

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a website which gets data from two 'different' MySql database tables. The tables have identical layouts (so the numbers in each table differs but 100% similar in ID's and column names). Now I am a complete self-made programming noob so bear with me in the following.

On the websites front page I display some data from both of the two tables. The way I do this is by creating a variable ($tableName) that holds the name of the table I need. This variable is then used for generating the necessary data in another file (data.php) and then displaying that data on the front page by the file design.php. This process is replicated for all tables in the MySql database. (below is a very simplified format).

Frontpage.php:

```
        <?php   
            include('../connection.php');   
        ?>

        <?php
            $tableName = table1;
            include('../Data.php'); 
            include('../Design.php');   
        ?>

        <?php
            $tableName = table2;
            include('../Data.php'); 
            include('../Design.php');   
        ?>
        .....(etc.)
```

Data.php:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM {$tableName} WHERE ID = 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die('error');      
while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    For ($n = 0; $n < 1; $n++){
        $dataVariable = $data["columnname"];                    
    }
}
```

Design.php

```
<a href="Ultimate.php"><?php echo $dataVariable; ?></a>
```

So what happens is that the user goes to the $dataVariable link and is then sent to Ultimate.php which also includes the Data.php file in order to display a hell-uv-alot of data. I therefore have to again declare the $tableName variable in the Ultimate.php file and then duplicate the Ultimate.php file for every single table there is in the MySql database and change href-link in the Design.php file. (very annoying).

My question is: how can I pass on my $tableName variable from the href on the front page to Ultimate.php? I have searched on here and found a way which includes $tableName to the URL opened on Ultimate.php whereafter I use $_GET inside Ultimate.php to collect it. For some reason I couldn't make that work - and i don't know if this is at all a solid way to solve things in my case.

More importantly: I have never worked with programming before so if anyone can advise me whether I am setting this up most efficiently or not that would also be great! I very much welcome links to guides/tutorials which you think might benefit me at this point!

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Why do you have multiple tables with identical structure in the first place? That is often a sign that something is wrong at the data model level already.

Comment: The tables contain data on different companies imported from Excel. The models are quite complex and I couldn't really imagine trying to combine the hundreds into one table.

Comment: @ChartProblems if they have identical data structure, there is almost never a reason to have such data in separate tables. In this example, all you'd need is another field such as `company_id`; and you could filter by "WHERE `company_id` = ?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="Ultimate.php?var=<?php echo $tableName; ?>"><?php echo $dataVariable; ?></a>
```

Then at the top of `Ultimate.php`:

```
<?php

$var = $_GET['var'];

?>
```

This takes the variable off the browser 
http://www.example.com/Ultimate.php?**var=yourvariable**

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't understand how I could spend hours on that one.

Comment: Please, beware that this solution opens up a breach for SQL Injection. Be sure to protect your website against it in case you use this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass variables from a hyperlink to another page using GET.

```
<a href="Ultimate.php?key=value&key2=value">hyperlink text</a>

$_GET['key']
```

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php#refsect1-reserved.variables.get-examples